# Can I accidentally publish an artefact to a public repo with maven clean deploy?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I haven't really dealt with the server side (i.e. repo integration/interaction) of maven so far, so this question is probably beyond naive, but I'm a bit puzzled by how maven deploys artefacts (like `jar` files).

We have maven central configured as repo in the maven settings.xml on our Jenkins build server, and a local nexus as mirror (for as far as I can tell).

What I want to achieve is to install our jars in the local `.m2` repository, and to make them available company-wide in our nexus repo. (My team has one, but the person who set it up has long left the company, and my expertise on nexus is basically nil.)

If I run `mvn clean deploy`, what are the chances of me accidentally pushing our `jar` onto a public repo? What's the right way to prevent that from happening? (Links to the right docs/maven manuals welcome.)

Comment: Without appropriate credentials to Maven central the chance will be zero...Apart from that defining maven central for download and not going via your repository manager shows there is something wrong. You should configure  to use your nexus as mirror for Maven central and internally only communicate with your repository manager....